# Expectations, covariances and correlations

Tags: r, probability, correlation, covariance, expectations

This is the question I am trying to solve. Create a sample of 10,000 pairs (X,Y). Using the above facts, estimateE(X), E(X^2), E(Y ), E(Y^2) and E(XY ) from your sample of data. Hence, compute an estimate of the correlation between the times X and Y in a pair (X, Y ). (You should write your own code for this calculation, without using any special R functions for finding a correlation.)

The pairs (X,Y) are created using a function that was created. My initial thought for answering this question is the code I wrote below. But I am getting errors on the first line saying 'object X is not found'. I also spoke to my lecturer about this problem and he said 'that it was the right idea, it just wasn't the right probability generating function.' How can I solve this?

```
pairs(10000) #This produces 10,000 pairs of (X,Y)

EX = (1/10000)* sum(X)

EX

EXsquared = (1/10000)*sum(X^2)

EXsquared 

EY= (1/10000)*sum(Y)

EYsquared = (1/10000)*sum(Y^2)

EYsquared

VarX = EXsquared - (EX)^2
VarY = EYsquared - (EY)^2

covXY = EXY - EX*EY #Now need to calculate EXY

EXY= (1/10000)*sum*(XY)

CovXY

Corr = CovXY / (VarX*VarY)^0.5

Corr
```

Thank you.

This is the function pairs:

```
pairs = function(nreps)

{X = S1 = 30 + rexp(nreps, rate = 1 / 15)
  F1 = runif(nreps, 0, 60)
  S2 = 30 + rexp(nreps, rate = 1 / 15)
  Y = S2 + max(X - F1, 0)
  cbind(X, Y)
}
```

Here X and Y are included in the function.

Comment: Have a look at r <- pairs(10000). Check r...

Comment: You need to generate two vectors `X` and `Y` first. Like this: `X <- rnorm(10000)`.

Comment: oh sorry I have now included the function in the question, is this what you mean?

Comment: You need to assign the output of `pairs()` to a variable, such as `dat <- pairs(10000)`. The class will be `matrix` which will require that you access the data with dat[,'X']. If you prefer to use `X` and `Y`, you will need to assign as follows: `X <- dat[,'X']` & `Y <- dat[,'Y']`. You could wrap the `pairs` function with a `data.frame` call to convert the matrix. The dataframe will permit you to access the data like this: `dat$X` and `dat$Y'. You should be okay until you get to the covariance; some code will need to be modified there.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you Edward, my expectations now all work. What is wrong with my covariance and correlation, it seems to work when I run it?

Comment: You have probably changed your code, but currently you use `EXY` before you compute it...  Also `*sum*(XY)` is probably not doing what you want.

Comment: oh yes, made that change already. But thank you!!